Converting UTC Column into datetime in python pandas
I would like to ask for little support. I have here a python frame containing data giving in UTC format. I would like to transform the column into date-format.
Order Date
15-Feb-2024 UTC
17-Feb-2024 UTC
18-Feb-2024 UTC
02-Apr-2024 UTC
05-Mar-2024 UTC
04-Mar-2024 UTC
11-Apr-2024 UTC
12-Apr-2024 UTC
16-Mar-2024 UTC
04-Apr-2024 UTC
05-Feb-2024 UTC
05-Mar-2024 UTC
14-Apr-2024 UTC


df["Order Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Order Date"],utc=True,format='%d-%b-%Y')

Applying the line above gives me the following error
time data "15-Feb-2024 UTC" doesn't match format "%d-%b-%Y", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

I tried all the options, without success.
Can someone tell me where the issue is?
All I need is to transform the column to a date column. I'd be grateful for any support

Did you try format='%d-%b-%Y UTC', or format='%d-%b-%Y %Z'?

Yes, it simply gives the the same answer to test the options given in my first comment

I just tried both of those format strings and they worked correctly on "04-May-2024 UTC".

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Order Date': ['15-Feb-2024 UTC', '17-Feb-2024 UTC', '18-Feb-2024 UTC', '02-Apr-2024 UTC', '05-Mar-2024 UTC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
    Order Date
0   15-Feb-2024 UTC
1   17-Feb-2024 UTC
2   18-Feb-2024 UTC
3   02-Apr-2024 UTC
4   05-Mar-2024 UTC

Code
if you want convert to datetime64[ns, UTC]
out = pd.to_datetime(df["Order Date"], utc=True, format='%d-%b-%Y UTC')

out:
0   2024-02-15 00:00:00+00:00
1   2024-02-17 00:00:00+00:00
2   2024-02-18 00:00:00+00:00
3   2024-04-02 00:00:00+00:00
4   2024-03-05 00:00:00+00:00
Name: Order Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

or if you want convert to datetime[ns]
out = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'].str.replace(' UTC', ''))

out:
0   2024-02-15
1   2024-02-17
2   2024-02-18
3   2024-04-02
4   2024-03-05
Name: Order Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

